# Отключение и включение скринсейвера

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-10

Как отключить/включить скринсавер в Win10 ?
Стандартные способы опробованные ниже не работают:

```
bool ret1, ret2, check = TRUE;

while (check)
{
    if (!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &ret1, 0))
    {
        cout << "SystemParametersInfo error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, 0, &ret2, 0))
    {
        cout << "SystemParametersInfo error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if ((ret1) || (ret2))
    {
        check = FALSE;
        cout << "ScreenSaver ON" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "ScreenSaver OFF" << endl;

    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Подозреваю что надо как то проверять SC_MONITORPOWER, но вот как это cделать?

Comment: О каких "стандартные способах, опробованных ниже" вы ведете речь? Приведенный код только опрашивает статус скринсейвера, но не делает никаких попыток отключить/включить его. Очевидным экспериментом было бы попробовать `SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE`, но у вас этого не видно.

Comment: Я не стал приводить весь код, это не имело смысла, по причине невозможности определить на текущий момент запущен он или нет. А убивается он Post/Send(Message), это не сложно.. Это просто кусок теста :) и он не работает на окнах 10, хотя на msdn других рекомендаций нет.

Comment: SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE - сейчас попробую почитать, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Отключить и включить это [SystemParametersInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa). SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE и SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE.
А чтобы запустить следующая команда;

```
SendMessage (GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо Андрей, только в окнах 10 это не срабатывает, возможно это связано с MinGW - хотя сомневаюсь, это чистое winAPI.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить задачу от имени администратора.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я и так он :) нет привычки плодить сущности на окнах :)